# Using sentence, turn intense into incense; what tool do I need?

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle, letters

#### Puzzle

What tool do I need to turn intense into incense, using sentence?

The same tool can turn dated into demented, using statement.

---

#### Hints

(Kudos: the accepted answer was published before the hints.)

Hint 1:

> sEntEncE and (respectively) sTaTemenT will work as well.

Hint 2 (it's a tiny puzzle by itself):

> PO6

Comment: This is so clever!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The 'tool' is

> `sed`, the UNIX "stream editor" program which applies edit commands to text.

> “sentence” and “statement” are to be interpreted as sed replacement commands (which search for text matching a pattern, and replace it with a different piece of text): `s/nt/nc/` and `s/a/emen/`. (As hexomino pointed out, the character after `s` doesn’t  have to be a slash; the character after `s` is treated as the delimiter. Those are `e` and `t` respectively in these cases.) Each one transforms the first word into the second.

> Commands (for Unix/Linux) that prove it:
>  `echo intense | sed sentence`
>  `echo dated   | sed statement`

Comment: Note that rot13(lbh pna ghea sebfg vagb evzr hfvat pevzr).

Comment: Hint 2 explained: rot13(cbfvk)